# Event listener for key class behaves unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, html, css

The log for the `closeBox` function is supposed to be `box hidden` but its not. its showing `box shown hidden`.
Can anyone explain why the classes of the box is not what is expected? This is the code:

```js
const showBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.showBox');
const closeBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBox');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

const showBox = function () {
  box.classList.add('will-show');
    box.classList.remove('hidden');
  box.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
    box.classList.remove('will-show');
        box.classList.add('shown');

    console.log(box.classList.value);
  });
}

const closeBox = function () {
  box.classList.add('will-hide');
  //shown class was removed here
  box.classList.remove('shown');
  box.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
    box.classList.remove('will-hide');
    box.classList.add('hidden');

    //supposed to be box hidden only
    console.log(box.classList.value);
  });
}

showBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', showBox);
closeBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', closeBox);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
  display:flex;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px);

    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0), translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.will-show {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

.will-hide {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="showBox">Show</button>
<button class="closeBox">Close</button>

<div class="box hidden"></div>
```

Comment: You don't actually need classes for shown **and** hidden. You only need the `hidden` class. Add it when something should be hidden and just remove it when it should be shown. This is the source of your problem - - the confusion between when to add and remove two classes.

Comment: Its something else. Its not so much about it being hidden or shown but the classes it has are not what's expected.

Comment: I know and that's because of the confusion about when to add/remove `shown` and when to add/remove `hidden`. Just remove the `shown` class and only worry about adding/removing the `hidden` class and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `.addEventListener("animationed")` will fire when your animation ends, for both when your box is shown and when it is closed. You can add the `{once: true}` option to your addEventListener to only add the listener once so it doesn't fire on subsequent animationed events:

```js
const showBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.showBox');
const closeBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBox');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

const showBox = function() {
  box.classList.add('will-show');
  box.classList.remove('hidden');
  box.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    box.classList.remove('will-show');
    box.classList.add('shown');
    console.log(box.classList.value);
  }, {once: true});
}

const closeBox = function() {
  box.classList.add('will-hide');
  //shown class was removed here
  box.classList.remove('shown');
  box.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    box.classList.remove('will-hide');
    box.classList.add('hidden');

    //supposed to be box hidden only
    console.log(box.classList.value);
  }, {once: true});
}

showBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', showBox);
closeBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', closeBox);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0), translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.will-show {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

.will-hide {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="showBox">Show</button>
<button class="closeBox">Close</button>

<div class="box hidden"></div>
```

Comment: This was it, thanks. can you also explain why when I tried to remove the add a removeEventListener inside, it still did not work? Here, https://jsfiddle.net/uj1kqwfL/

Comment: @ProsyArceno To remove the event listener correctly, you need to pass through the same function reference (you have two unique functions)

Comment: It still doesn't work properly when clicked multiple times. It hides the square when clicked show button second time. In order for `{once: true}` to work, the the same function must be registered in both listeners. In that case it's better in every way to simply register that function once outside another listener instead.

Comment: This is fine. I wasn't looking for a better implementation. Just an explanation. I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you register a new `animationend` event listener each time you click a button.

So when you click `Close` button it fires both `close` and `show` events listeners.

You'll need either remove that event when it's complete, or register it once:

```js
const showBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.showBox');
const closeBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBox');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

box.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
  if (box.classList.contains("will-hide"))
  {
    box.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  else
  {
    box.classList.add('shown');
  }
  box.classList.remove('will-hide');
  box.classList.remove('will-show');
  console.log(box.classList.value);
});
const showBox = function () {
  if (box.classList.contains("shown"))
    return;

  box.classList.add('will-show');
  box.classList.remove('hidden');
}

const closeBox = function () {
  if (box.classList.contains("hidden"))
    return;

  box.classList.add('will-hide');
  //shown class was removed here
  box.classList.remove('shown');
}

showBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', showBox);
closeBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', closeBox);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
  display:flex;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px);

    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0), translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.will-show {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

.will-hide {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="showBox">Show</button>
<button class="closeBox">Close</button>

<div class="box hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

implemented a little state-machine. This is nicer/less jumpy when someone clicks the show/close buttons multiple times.

```js
const showBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.showBox');
const closeBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBox');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

// what are the allowed state-changes
const stateChanges = {
  "hidden": {
    "will-show": true
  },
  "will-hide": {
    "hidden": true,
    //"will-show": true
  },
  "shown": {
    "will-hide": true
  },
  "will-show": {
    "shown": true,
    //"will-hide": true
  }
};

const setState = (toState) => {
  for (let fromState in stateChanges) {
    if (box.classList.contains(fromState) && stateChanges[fromState][toState]) {
      box.classList.remove(fromState);
      box.classList.add(toState);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


const showBox = function() {
  setState('will-show');
}

const closeBox = function() {
  setState('will-hide');
}

const animationend = function() {
  //meh, try which one works
  setState('shown') || setState('hidden');
  console.log(box.classList.value);
}

showBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', showBox);
closeBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', closeBox);
box.addEventListener("animationend", animationend);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0), translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.will-show {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

.will-hide {
  animation: slide-in-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="showBox">Show</button>
<button class="closeBox">Close</button>

<div class="box hidden"></div>
```

I'm not sure about the state changes "will-hide" -> "sill-show" and vice versa.
That's why I commented them out. If you don't need them/won't allow them, you can simplify that part to:

```js
const stateChanges = {
  "hidden": "will-show",
  "will-show": "shown",
  "shown": "will-hide",
  "will-hide": "hidden"
}

// and

if (box.classList.contains(fromState) && stateChanges[fromState] === toState) {
```